# generate URL by using relative paths without redirection

Tags: javascript

In my javascript code I want to be able to retrieve current URL and then generate a new URL by adding relative paths (all of this without actually redirecting to new place, just want the URL string reference to pass on).

For eg: - this is exactly what I want but minus the redirection that kicks in

```
window.location.href = "../../";
var url = window.location.href;
```

I just want the result of appending relative path to current url and retrieve the new URL in string format.

EDIT with example to make the question more clear.

Suppose the current URL is:

```
www.example.com/level1/level2/level3/index.html
```

Now I want to get the URL 2 levels back:

```
www.example.com/level1
```

Comment: Well if you just want the reference you can do var url = window.location.href + "../../"; But I guess this is not what you really are asking? Not sure why redirection kicks in for you, might be missing some code

Comment: yeah appending "../../" just gives me a string - i want to resolve that into a proper URL - href internally seems to do it but also redirects

Comment: What is the problem? question is not clear at all

Comment: say the current url in location bar is www.example.com/level1/level2/leve3/index.html

Now I want to get a URL two levels back .i.e: www.example.com/level1

Comment: @charlietfl The problem is clear. He wants `parsePath('http://example.com/lv1/lv2/lv3', '../../') -> 'http://example.com/lv1'`

Comment: Short answer: Use an anchor element's `.href` instead of `document.location`'s.

Comment: there is no anchor in my page - I just want to resolve based on my current location

Comment: Is it always a, I want to go back 2 directories action or do you want to apply a string path to the path in question? Still not clear. I'd know how to do exactly what you're asking here by splitting the url and removing the last 2 elements before imploding again...